# Issues creating slope raster layer from a point layer

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation, slope

I'm trying to create a slope raster layer using QGIS 2.0 on Windows XP.

I started with a points layer with the Z elevation attribute.

[image: points]

I then used the interpolation plugin to create a DEM.

[image]

But, when I used the Raster Terrain Analysis plugin, it gave me a strange output. What can I be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: What settings did you is? What projection is the data in? I have had issues in the past with data in a geographic projection

Comment: You need to use a modified interpolation method since your z points are not equally distributed but along the contour lines. For inspiration, see http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM

Comment: projection: RGPF UTM Zone 6S

Comment: would doing IDW interpolation through raster --> interpolation be a "modified interpolation" method? I've been playing around with GRASS tools in processing toolbox: s.surf.bspline and v.surf.IDW (but get error signals saying the raster cannot be loaded). using the GRASS toolbox, I end up with very large pixels.