# Slope regions from elevation points using QGIS 2.0

Tags: qgis, raster

I am using QGIS to create a layer of slope region polygons (e.g. less than 30% slope, 30-50%, more than 50% categories). My data comes from point elevations and I interpolated using SAGA b-spline approximation. I then used the Raster Terrain plugin to calculate slope. However, after using the raster calculator and polygonizing the categories of interest, I still have a problem in terms of how neat the borders are. I read about region growing, but am not sure if I have enough information to do so/how to do it.

This above image resembles what I'm aiming for. The bottom image is what I currently have.

[image]

Comment: would http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97864/issues-creating-slope-raster-layer-from-a-point-layer help?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson This was another post of mine to tackle my issue trying to interpolate. Now, it's a question of vectorizing my raster layer--creating contiguous polygons of elevation categories. Currently, I have a million little pixel-shaped polygons that I would like to combine based on elevation category.